# Scala loop returns as Unit and compiler points to "for" syntax?

Tags: scala, return-type

Seems like Unit is the theme of my troubles today. I'm porting a JSON deserializer that uses Gson and when it comes to this for loop:

```
  def deserialize(json:JsonElement, 
                  typeOfT:Type, 
                  context:JsonDeserializationContext) = {
    var eventData = new EventData(null, null)
    var jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject
    for(entry <- jsonObject.entrySet()) {
      var key = entry.getKey()
      var element = entry.getValue()
      element
      if("previous_attributes".equals(key)) {
        var previousAttributes = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Object]()
        populateMapFromJSONObject(previousAttributes, element.getAsJsonObject())
        eventData.setPreviousAttributes(previousAttributes)
        eventData
      } else if ("object".equals(key)) {
        val `type` = element.getAsJsonObject().get("object").getAsString()
        var cl = objectMap.get(`type`).asInstanceOf[StripeObject]
        var `object` = abstractObject.retrieve(cl, key)
        eventData.setObject(`object`)
        eventData
      }
    }
  }
```

The compiler spits out the error `type mismatch; found : Unit required: com.stripe.EventData` and it points to this line here: `for(entry <- jsonObject.entrySet())`

**Questions**

1. Confirm that it is indeed the Gson method `entrySet()` appearing as unit?
2. If not, what part of the code is creating the issue? I've set return types/values for `eventData` class methods
3. Is there a workaround for the Gson Unit issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you don't mind my reformatting of your code. It was difficult to see what was going on with the indentation all out of place. Spaces vs Tabs issue, I presume.

Comment: Not a problem I coudn't figure out how to make it pretty! thanks for doing so, i need to set eclipse tab formatting properly LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error was rather cryptic and there are actually inherent issues here. First the fundamentals thanks to a colleague:

1. A Scala for loop doesn't return and instead a list needs to be built up in order to return it afterwards.
2. A map naturally returns on-the-fly with each iteration.

Second, the issue I was having was caused by my own bug. I forgot to return `eventData` at the end of the method so in the end I got this nice clean function:

```
@SuppressWarnings(Array("unchecked"))
  def deserialize(json:JsonElement, typeOfT:Type, context:JsonDeserializationContext) = {
    var eventData = new EventData(null, null)
    var jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject
    for(entry <- jsonObject.entrySet()) {

      var key = entry.getKey()
            var element = entry.getValue()
            if("previous_attributes".equals(key)) {
                var previousAttributes = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Object]()
                populateMapFromJSONObject(previousAttributes, element.getAsJsonObject())
                eventData.setPreviousAttributes(previousAttributes)
            } else if ("object".equals(key)) {
                val `type` = element.getAsJsonObject().get("object").getAsString()
                var cl = objectMap.get(`type`).asInstanceOf[StripeObject]
                var `object` = abstractObject.retrieve(cl, key)
                eventData.setObject(`object`)
            }
    }
    eventData
  }
```

I was confused by the compiler pointing to the middle of the for loop, but really it was referring to what was being returned by the method and not the Gson object.

Comment: Yes. The compiler points at the expression returning the `Unit`, here a for construct.